Can I use the Estimate of a model directly without considering the p-value?
This is a follow-up question of (About Multivariate Generalized Regression Mixed Models with negative binomial distribution). The research question is to get the intraindividual (within-subject) variations on contact patterns per period. Each participant reports their contact information for at least two time points. There are three periods, the baseline is before the lockdown.
A plot about the contact rates per age group and location is like this:

Zero contacts are added to the data. When a participant reports contact at the location of the household, it means that there is no contact at the other locations, therefore, the outcome variable (number of contacts) includes a lot of zero.
The model I construct is like this:
glmmTMB(n ~ period * age_4cat * ( sex + I(hh_size) + region + 
    employment_2cat + education_2cat + weekend + marital_2cat) +
    (1 | token) + (1 | Bundesland) + (1 | age_4cat),
    family = nbinom2, ziformula = ~1, 
    # because outcome has high proportion of 0
    data = data_education)
 
# age_4cat is the four age categories
# data_education is the contact information at the location of Education

Then the summary of the model is a long list. This is part of the result that answer the research question.
period2:age_4cat0-25:sexFemale                             -0.093847        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:sexFemale                              0.033543   0.937228   0.036    0.971    
period2:age_4cat26-45:sexFemale                             0.160372   3.484614   0.046    0.963    
period3:age_4cat26-45:sexFemale                            -0.178296   1.997667  -0.089    0.929    
period2:age_4cat46-65:sexFemale                             0.738602        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat46-65:sexFemale                             0.492707        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat0-25:I(hh_size)                             0.509198        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:I(hh_size)                            -0.049860   0.280216  -0.178    0.859    
period2:age_4cat26-45:I(hh_size)                            0.542733        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat26-45:I(hh_size)                           -0.343575        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat46-65:I(hh_size)                            0.647815   1.139068   0.569    0.570    
period3:age_4cat46-65:I(hh_size)                            0.113820        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat0-25:regionEast Germany                    -0.184194   0.177052  -1.040    0.298    
period3:age_4cat0-25:regionEast Germany                    -0.358630   2.630182  -0.136    0.892    
period2:age_4cat26-45:regionEast Germany                    0.293064        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat26-45:regionEast Germany                    0.730155   2.832746   0.258    0.797    
period2:age_4cat46-65:regionEast Germany                   -0.534995        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat46-65:regionEast Germany                    0.141923   2.951278   0.048    0.962    
period2:age_4cat0-25:employment_2catNot Employed            0.262844        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:employment_2catNot Employed            0.059230   2.281125   0.026    0.979    
period2:age_4cat26-45:employment_2catNot Employed           0.344246        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat26-45:employment_2catNot Employed           0.258395   1.535815   0.168    0.866    
period2:age_4cat46-65:employment_2catNot Employed           0.134121        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat46-65:employment_2catNot Employed          -0.725622        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat0-25:education_2catNon-Higher Education     0.448545        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:education_2catNon-Higher Education     0.339487        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat26-45:education_2catNon-Higher Education   -0.719402        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat26-45:education_2catNon-Higher Education    0.112603   1.560972   0.072    0.942    
period2:age_4cat46-65:education_2catNon-Higher Education    0.291454        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat46-65:education_2catNon-Higher Education   -0.437684   1.626772  -0.269    0.788    
period2:age_4cat0-25:weekendNot weekend                     0.085879        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:weekendNot weekend                     0.366046   3.780621   0.097    0.923    
period2:age_4cat26-45:weekendNot weekend                   -0.063371        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat26-45:weekendNot weekend                    0.176045   2.319626   0.076    0.940    
period2:age_4cat46-65:weekendNot weekend                   -0.043144   3.167738  -0.014    0.989    
period3:age_4cat46-65:weekendNot weekend                    0.438728   2.939998   0.149    0.881    
period2:age_4cat0-25:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant   0.043230        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant   0.575552        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period2:age_4cat26-45:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant  0.002831   1.667829   0.002    0.999    
period3:age_4cat26-45:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant  0.332741   2.255592   0.148    0.883    
period2:age_4cat46-65:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant  0.421758   3.567127   0.118    0.906    
period3:age_4cat46-65:marital_2catmarried/childparticipant  0.004881   1.756693   0.003    0.998 

What I want to get from this result is that at the location of Education, between three periods and four age groups, what are the variables associated with the variations of the number of contacts at the individual level.
The results is strange, there is only one statistically significant variable, and many NaN. Can I use the Estimate to answer the research question?
period2:age_4cat0-25:sexFemale                             -0.093847        NaN     NaN      NaN    
period3:age_4cat0-25:sexFemale                              0.033543   0.937228   0.036    0.971

Like for the result above, can I say that the age group 0-25, being female tends to have fewer contacts during period 2 and higher contacts during period 3?

What do the columns in your output table represent? Point estimates, standard error, and p-value?

@Durden Yes, Estimate, Std. Error, z value, Pr(>|z|)

Why are so many of them undefined?

I think it may be because 80% of the outcome are 0


Like for the result above, can I say that the age group 0-25, being female tends to have fewer contacts during period 2 and higher contacts during period 3?

Given that the NaN are probably due to lack of information for estimating the variability of certain estimators (which may well have to do with the "80% outcomes zero" mentioned in a comment), an NaN isn't really more "significant" than an insignificant p-value. Given that this is so, if you interpret estimators only, statements hold for the observed data only. This in particular means that they don't allow for generalisation.
Insignificant or NaN p-values indicate that there is no clear evidence against any difference visible being meaningless and due to random variation, so if you suppress p-values and just say "in the age group 0-25, being female tends to have fewer contacts during period 2 and higher contacts during period 3", you may well interpret meaningless noise, which you better avoid.

Thank you, Christian. Later after I posted the question, I read a paper and built the model with the mgcv package following instructions from that paper.
